# what is antonym of "simultaneous"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Dears
what word shall be used for saying that two events must not take place at same time?
For example to say that two machines in a room must not simultaneously work. One shall run only after other one turned off.

Comment: What was the answer deleted? Check a good dictionary.

Comment: Never use the word *dear* like this. Ever.

Comment: @tchrist - The use of "dear" in that sense is very common in subcontinent English (i.e. Pakistan/India/Bangladesh). It may be wrong for US/UK/etc. but it appears to be standard there.

Comment: Google `antonym simultaneous`

Answer (score 2):

If the second machine only ever runs after the first has completed its work you could describe their operation as sequential. Otherwise I think exclusive is the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a word or stock phrase that unambiguously captures that idea, but you might say that the two machines have **mutually exclusive** operation: neither can run while the other does.

Comment: Mutually exclusive implies one does NOT run if the other has.

Comment: @moonstar2001 - Not true.

Answer (score 0):

The two best words for this sentence in my mind are

> The two machines must be used **non-simultaneously**.

and

> The two machines must be used **asynchronously**.

“Non-simultaneously” is a perfectly good word that has definitions in the [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/nonsimultaneous) and [Oxford English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/non-simultaneous) dictionaries (though not in Miriam Webster).

I’m not sure why moonstar thinks that “asynchronously” requires randomness. [Miriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asynchronous) defines it as “not simultaneous or concurrent in time“ and the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/asynchronous) defines it as “Not existing or occurring at the same time.”

“Synchronously” is also a word you can use, and is a synonym for “simultaneously.”

Comment: @downvoter I would love feedback on why you don’t like this answer.

Comment: A user who commented on a now-deleted post said "*In engineering, to say that two processes are asynchronous doesn't mean that they cannot run at the same time: it means that one starts the other but doesn't need to wait for the other to finish before it proceeds*" Not being an engineer myself, I cannot say if their observation is pertinent or not but it might explain the DV.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That’s true, but it’s a specific technical use and not the standard usage of the term.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP is asking a specific technical question. I only wanted to relate another user's comment to an almost identical answer, deleted before you posted, that seemed relevant to your case.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Fair.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't one single antonym. Depending on the context you may use :

1. Sequential (if it is one after another)
2. Asynchronous (if events occur at random points of time)

Comment: Your definition of asynchronous is wrong.

Comment: thanks everyone. for me "non-simultaneous" works good. i just see it is very uncommon word.